# ReactJS Select Key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `Select` that get's values from API,
then on change it gets the value from the select and renders a table. but I want the select to display `planet.id` and `planet.name`, but doing it using `event.target.value` wont work since it would pass both values and table wouldn't render!
Any way of doing this passing for example `key={planet.id}`?

```js
class Planet extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: 1};
       
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event){
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    render () {

        let planets = this.props.state.planets;
        let optionItems = planets.map((planet) =>
                <option key={planet.id} >{planet.id}</option>
            );
```

Comment: where is `value` property in `<option>` tag?

Comment: add `value`  property to `<option>`.

Comment: @Raviteja after adding a value={planet.id} made it work, but strangely it was working without the value property?

Comment: You'll able to select any option. To save the selected option you need `value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean this?:

`<option key={planet.id} value={planet.id} >{planet.id}-{planet.name}</option>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<option key={planet.id} value={planet.id}>{planet.name}</option>
```